# Condição em trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sobre a seguinte trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_TESTE] 
   ON  [MINHABASE].[dbo].[TB_DOCUMENTOS] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @DOC INT
DECLARE @QTD FLOAT

SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ID, @DOC = DOCUMENTO, @QTD = QUANTIDADE
FROM dbo.TB_DOCUMENTOS 
WHERE OPERACAO = 177
AND STATUS = 1
ORDER BY ID DESC

-- CONDICAO

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE dbo.TB_DOCUMENTOS
SET PESO = 1000
WHERE ID = @ID

END
```

Na query, faço o filtro e defino as variáveis `@ID, @DOC, @QTD`.

Quando essa consulta **NÃO retorna** um registro, a trigger irá executar o `update` dentro do `BEGIN`, mesmo que eu não tenha uma condição  acima ?

Comment: Esse procedimento de gatilho está muito estranho... Ele não consulta as informações recebidas nas tabelas virtuais INSERTED e DELETED.

Comment: Caso o processamento esteja lento, avalie a possibilidade de criar índice pela coluna ID, filtrado por `OPERACAO` 177 e `STATUS` 1 e que seja de cobertura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode usar uma condicional para garantir a integridade do código, neste caso ele não vai executar o update mas tentará, o que vai gerar um processo...

```
IF @ID != '' THEN
UPDATE dbo.TB_DOCUMENTOS
  SET PESO = 1000
  WHERE ID = @ID
END IF
```

Comment: Ele tentará executar um update em nada então !? Melhor eu colocar as condições do WHERE no IF da trigger então !?

Comment: O select será feito de qualquer forma, até mais enxuto com o where. o where do update é necessário.

Comment: O select sim. Ok. O `update` será executado se não trouxer nenhum registro do `select` (como você disse na resposta), então ele tenta aplicar um `update` em nenhum registro ? Não irá afetar nada, mas ele irá executar !?

Answer (score 0):

No *sql-server* você pode usar [**`IF`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), ou seja, a estrutura da *proc* pode ser mantida, e onde você deixou "reservado" para `-- CONDICAO`, entre com o seguinte:

```
IF @ID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   ...
END
```

Comment: a parte de fazer a condição, tranquilo, a dúvida é: O update será executado se não trouxer nenhum registro do select ? Caso sim, então ele tenta aplicar um update em nenhum registro ? Não irá afetar nada, mas ele irá executar !?

Comment: se você fizer a validação antes, garantidamente ele não executa, já que não entra no bloco. Mas na questão de processamento, não sei como o sql-server procede quando se tenta um `update` "em nada"